# OpenVidu: Coturn server not used as a TURN server

Tags: kurento, stun, turn, coturn, openvidu

I deployed an OpenVidu server using AWS CloudFormation.

The OpenVidu server can be deployed successfully and it appears to be working properly.

However, I found that the associated Kurento server is using the installed Coturn server as a STUN server.  (The file /etc/kurento/modules/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini has the line "turnURL=user:password@address:port" commented, while the lines "stunServerAddress=" and "stunServerPort=3478" are uncommented.)

While the Coturn server can function as a TURN server, I wonder why the Kurento server is not configured to use the Coturn server as a TURN server, in order to enjoy richer set of features.

Comment: I think this due to the fact, that Kurento only needs a TURN server configured in case it itself runs in a restrictive Firewall/NAT environment. It has nothing to do with the clients which might need TURN to connect to Kurento.